# With paper.js inserting pointtext to canvas pushes other items away 

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I'm trying to create a rectangle and a pointtext element, where the rectangle will be the
text element's container.

Without text element, everything works fine. When text element inserted, rectangle is pushed away. Well, rectangle is displayed at the correct position, but the points where it receives the events are pushed away.

Please see http://jsbin.com/abejim/1

Rectangle's visibility should increase when hovered. Hovering does not affect, but when mouse moved to 580,280 and around , it's visibility increases.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That jsbin seems to be working fine for me in Firefox.  The rectangle is displayed in the correct location and hovering over the rectangle makes it highlight.  Possibly the paper.js code has updated since you asked the question.

---

It looks like you asked the same question on the paper.js [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/paperjs).  For future reference here, the response was:

> pointtext takes relative coordinates and you r trying to give absolute coordinates.
>   try this one:

```
var size = new paper.Size(125, 75);    //SM size to paper size
var rectangle = new paper.Rectangle({ x: 0, y: 0 }, size);    //(top_left, bottom_right)
var cornerSize = new paper.Size(10, 10);    //rounding of edges
var shape = new paper.Path.RoundRectangle(rectangle, cornerSize);
shape.strokeWidth = 3;
shape.strokeColor = '#525252';
shape.fillColor = '#FFFFFF';
shape.name = 'shape';
var stateNameTxt = new paper.PointText(10, 65);
stateNameTxt.content = state_name;
stateNameTxt.name = 'stateNameTxt';
var state = new paper.Group();    //create group
state.name = state_name;
state.opacity = 0.8;
state.addChild(shape);    //add shape to grpup
state.addChild(stateNameTxt);    //add pointtext  to group
```